# I try to create a typescript project but the javascript project is created

Tags: typescript

I try to create a typescript project with the npx create-react-app my-app --template typescript command, but the javascript project is created

and by changing the .js extension to .tsx, I get the following error:

Could not find a required file.
Name: index.js
Searched in: /home/path/Projects/my-app/src

Comment: Make sure you have the latest version of Create React App installed globally by running the command:
npm install -g create-react-app

Comment: did you restarted your development server!?

Comment: Farideh Khanum, try running the command with the --typescript flag instead of --template typescript:

npx create-react-app my-app --typescript

Comment: @vsam Global installs of create-react-app are no longer supported.

Comment: I ran the npm install -g create-react-app command again and also the npx create-react-app my-app --typescript command but it brought up the javascript app again.